# Group By Multiple Columns, SUM at the first Group By Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am writing a query that groups over two columns. this means, it will put Col1 and Col2 in the same group.

How can I do a SUM of records based on Group Col1 ?

I have this so far: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eada2/1

Thank you

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: For each row, I want to show the total number of docuTypes within a single activity Id.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it as follows:

```
WITH cteActivityIds (activityId, allDocuByActivity)
AS
  (SELECT activityId, COUNT(*) AS allDocuByActivity FROM #ER GROUP BY activityId)
SELECT
      E.activityId AS [Actiivty ID],
      docuType AS [Docu Type],
      COUNT(docuType),
      CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,2), (COUNT(docuType) * 100.00 / t.allDocuByActivity)) [Total     DocuType in Activity],
      SUM(CASE WHEN [sent] != '1-1-1900' THEN 1 END) AS [Sent],
      SUM(CASE WHEN [approved] != '1-1-1900' THEN 1 END) AS [Approved]
FROM
      #ER AS E
INNER JOIN cteActivityIds AS t 
  ON E.activityId = t.activityId
GROUP BY
     E.activityId, docuType, t.allDocuByActivity
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that, in my opinion, looks a little cleaner - it does not require a join and uses 'partition by' to calculate the individual counts:

```
WITH activityCounts as (
    select
        activityId,
        docuType,
        count(activityId) OVER(PARTITION BY activityId) as activityIdCount,
        count(docuType) OVER(PARTITION BY activityId, docuType) as docuTypeCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN [sent] != '1-1-1900' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY activityId, docuType) AS [Sent],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [approved] != '1-1-1900' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY activityId, docuType) AS [Approved]
    from ER
)
SELECT
    activityId,
    docuType,
    docuTypeCount,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,2), (COUNT(docuTypeCount) * 100.00 / activityIdCount)) as [Total DocuType in Activity],
    [Sent],
    [Approved]
FROM activityCounts
GROUP BY
    activityId,
    docuType,
    activityIdCount,
    docuTypeCount,
    [Sent],
    [Approved]
```

Here is a [**link to sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eada2/23)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put an aggregate function on `t.allDocuByActivity`

```
MIN(t.allDocuByActivity) AS [Total DocuType in Activity],
```

However, since your label is `DocuType`. Don't you need `DISTINCT`?